# How do you choose a kernel for a discontinuous function in Gaussian Process Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, kernel, gaussian-process

I'm doing Gaussian Process Regression and created a series of functions by gluing other functions together on random places. Here's an example:

[image]

Perhaps this one is to complicated, but all the functions come from the same "family", they're all variations of gaussians. Is there anything standard that can be done with this?